# How can I use firebase auth with a steam game without asking the user to do anything?

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, steam, steamworks-api

I plan on releasing a game on steam.
This game uses firebase so when I start the game, I must authenticate to firebase to be able to make queries and comply with the security rules in place.

Right now, I have a field for email and password and the user has to log in every time which is a hassle.

Is there a solution that requires no server (so no custom auth provider) that enables me to log in the user without him doing anything ?

Thank you

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/anonymous-auth?

Comment: From what I understand, it's better to use anonymous auth if you upgrade it to a "real" account later, it that correct ? I'll still have a look, thank you